# Javascript 'Namespaces' and jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, prototype

I'm using the recommendations laid down here (http://www.odetocode.com/articles/473.aspx) to write a JavaScript AJAX webchat system using simulated **Namespacing** and prototyping.

In one of my prototype methods I'm calling the **$.ajax** method in **jQuery**. What I then want to do is pass the returned JSON data into a method inside my JavaScript webchat namespace.

The problem seems to be because I've created an instance of my JavaScript webchat, I can't directly call a method inside it because I need to address it through the instance.

The key part in the code below is

```
success: function(data, textStatus) {
  this.GetUpdate_Success(data)
},
```

I'm thinking because we're inside the $.ajax() method, that **this** no longer refers to our WebchatV3 object.

The full JavaScript code is shown below:

```
/// <reference path="/JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js" />

// Simulated 'namespace'
var AvonAndSomerset = {}

// Chatroom run time data
AvonAndSomerset.WebchatV3 = function(memberId, passcode) {
  this.Members = new Array(); // Members in the chatroom
  this.Questions = new Array(); // The questions queue in the chatroom

  // Details about the current user
  this.currentMember = new AvonAndSomerset.WebchatV3.Member(memberId, passcode, null, null, null, null, null);

  // Set-up AJAX defaults
  $.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
  });
}

AvonAndSomerset.WebchatV3.prototype = {
    // Get latest Member,Quetsion,Transcript and Room data from server
    GetUpdate: function(StartUp) {

      $.ajax({
        url: "JSON.aspx/Members_GetChanges",
        data: "{ MemberID: " + this.currentMember.memberId + ", Passcode: \"" + this.currentMember.passcode + "\", ReturnAll: " + StartUp + " }",
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
          this.GetUpdate_Success(data)
        },
        error: function(result) {
          alert('Members_GetChanges() failed: ' + result.responseText);
        }
      });
    },
    // Callback - on success of GetUpdate()
    GetUpdate_Success: function(data) {
      alert('The AJAX call was successful!');
    },
    // Does the MemberID exist in the local array?
    Members_DoesExist: function(MemberID) {
      alert('Searching for ' + MemberID);

      alert(this.Members.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to create a variable that references `this` at the proper scope required.  `this` and scope work differently in javascript then most languages, in this case it is referring to the object being passed into the function.

```
// Get latest Member,Quetsion,Transcript and Room data from server
GetUpdate: function(StartUp) {
    //here
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({ url: "JSON.aspx/Members_GetChanges",
        data: "{ MemberID: " + this.currentMember.memberId + ", Passcode: \"" + this.currentMember.passcode + "\", ReturnAll: " + StartUp + " }",
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            self.GetUpdate_Success(data)
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('Members_GetChanges() failed: ' + result.responseText);
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
success: function(data, textStatus) {
  AvonAndSomerset.WebchatV3.GetUpdate_Success(data)
},
```

That may work.